# Generate alphanumeric sequence with sql stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to Auto Generate Employee Reference number unique sequence with primary key. Sample Refno: (A0001-Z9999) now exeeded the maximum count(Z9999)
Next sequence I want to generate:

```
AA001-AA999,
AB001-AB999, 
AZ999-BA001
BC001-BZ999,
CA001-CZ999,
ZA001-ZZ999..LIKE THIS..IN sql server stored procedure..

...ZZ999 LIKE THIS
```

Comment: is it your home work we need to do or what ? what you have tried so far ? Post that

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this.

First create a SEQUENCE to generate integer sequence numbers starting from 1.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.MySeq AS INT
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Then create a stored procedure which generates a sequence code in the required format.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.up_GetNextSequence
(
    @seq nchar(5) out
)
AS
DECLARE @i int = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.MySeq;

IF @i > 685323
BEGIN
    RAISERROR(N'Sequence is out of range.', 16, 0);
END

IF @i < 10000
BEGIN
    SET @seq = N'A' + FORMAT(@i, 'D4');
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    DECLARE @j int;
    SET @j = @i - 9999;

    DECLARE @k int;
    SET @k = ((@j - 1) % 999) + 1;

    DECLARE @l int;
    SET @l = (@j - 1) / 999;

    DECLARE @m int;
    SET @m = (@l % 26) + 65;

    DECLARE @n int;
    SET @n = (@l / 26) + 65;

    SET @seq = NCHAR(@n) + NCHAR(@m) + FORMAT(@k, 'D3');
END;
```

Then test the stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @seq nchar(5);
EXEC up_GetNextSequence @seq output;
SELECT @seq AS '@seq'
```

[image]

Call it four more times and we get to "A0005".

[image]

To test the first breakpoint, alter the sequence object so that it returns 9999. Then execute the test code again.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.MySeq
   RESTART WITH 9999;
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

And so on...

```
ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.MySeq
    RESTART WITH 10998;
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.MySeq
    RESTART WITH 35973;
```

[image]

[image]

```
ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.MySeq
    RESTART WITH 659349;
```

[image]

[image]

To test what happens when it gets to the end of the allowed range.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.MySeq
    RESTART WITH 685323;
```

[image]

Execute the stored procedure one more time and it raises an error, saying the sequence is out of range. This is by design.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This query will give you all values you need:

```
--here we take all the english alphabet
;WITH chars AS (
SELECT CHAR(65) as chars, 65 as [level]
UNION ALL
SELECT CHAR([level]+1), [level]+1
FROM chars
WHERE [level]-65 < 25
), cte AS ( -- Here we take didits from 1 to 999
SELECT 1 as digits
UNION ALL
SELECT digits+1
FROM cte
WHERE digits < 999
), codes AS ( -- here we get all chars combinations "AA", "AB" etc
SELECT c1.chars+c2.chars as code
FROM chars c1
cross join chars c2
)

--And here come cortesian join to get all refnomes ou need
SELECT code + CASE WHEN LEN(digits) = 1 THEN CONCAT('00',cast(digits as nvarchar(1)))
            WHEN LEN(digits) = 2 THEN CONCAT('0',cast(digits as nvarchar(2)))
            ELSE cast(digits as nvarchar(3)) END  as Refno
FROM cte
CROSS JOIN codes
ORDER BY code
OPTION (maxrecursion 1000)
```

Output:

```
Refno
AA001
AA002
AA003
AA004
AA005
AA006
AA007
AA008
AA009
AA010
AA011
AA012
AA013
AA014
AA015
AA016
AA017
...
etc
ZZ999
```

~675324 rows

You can put the result into some table and in stored procedure return value you need from that table.